# How to clone Boost ASIO coroutine on fork?

Tags: boost, boost-asio, coroutine

Looking at the Boost ASIO http server [example with coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server4/server.cpp) I am wondering if the used cloning method is safe:

```
    // We "fork" by cloning a new server coroutine to handle the connection.
    // After forking we have a parent coroutine and a child coroutine. Both
    // parent and child continue execution at the following line. They can
    // be distinguished using the functions coroutine::is_parent() and
    // coroutine::is_child().
    fork server(*this)();
```

With that line a server object is copy constructed from the current object.

But isn't there the possibility that following happens:

1. the cloned child coroutine issues a yield
2. thus, the child's coroutine body is left
3. thus, the child's `operator()()` method is left
4. the parent destructs the child object
5. the parent starts a new iteration and yields
6. an async-method called by the child finishes
7. thus, the now (destructed) child coroutine is reentered

If it is safe, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent doesn't destruct the child object.

This is because the coroutine object *is* the actual completion handler to be invoked, and copies are being kept in the service's queue.

Because the fields are (usually) shared pointers, the actual data travels "lightly" from copy to copy, only being destructed when the last completion handler finished, and the coroutine is *exited*, instead of *yielded*.

---

An alternative to having all fields be shared-pointers might be to have the coroutine derive `enable_shared_from_this`, like many other Asio samples show. I haven't actually employed this with coroutines but I think it would have merit (to reduce the overhead of reference counting on yields) and can't immediately think of a reason why it wouldn't work for coroutines.

Comment: I see, it is safe because the child server object is copied around (e.g. as in `async_write(..., *this)`. Your comment regarding `enable_shared_from_this` is spot on - I was basically looking for it in that http server example - thus missing the completion-handler-copying pattern. I agree that using the shared pointer alternative would reduce overhead (i.e. resulting in one shared-pointer copy vs. 5 shared-pointer copies + 1 function object copy + 1 parser object copy).